# Parse error google maps javascript v3 on blackberry 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on worklight hybrid application in which I am using google maps v3 javascript API to load maps,whenver i am trying to load maps by using jquery ajax,I am getting **syntax error:parse error in main.js on line no 26**
The same ajax is working fine on other operating sytsem Android,BB10
This is only happening on blackberry 7(blackberry bold)

Please see below my code for

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.15&sensor=true&language=en&callback=loadmap',
        dataType: 'script',
        // Default to 10 seconds
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function () {

        },
        success:function(){
        }
    });
```

I

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Maps APIs FAQs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport), the Google Maps JavaScript API does not support the browser, or webview on BlackBerry 7. In fact, opening the [map-simple](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple) page on BB7 simulator would get a blank page.

In this case, consider using the [staticmaps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) instead.